# Disable swiping right on the home screen to Google news

Tags: samsung, home-screen, android-11, google-discover

I have a Samsung device running on Android 11. Swiping right on the home screen showing me some Google news propaganda. It is truly awful. It is just a bunch of hair-brained clickbait and lies.

I managed to disable it in settings.

Now, how can I prevent the swipe-right screen, or how can I replace it with a better app?

Comment: Long press an empty area on the home screen and swipe right to see a toggle button for the same. I don't think so if there is any replacement other than "samsung free".

Comment: Google are so rubbish at interfaces. Long press then tap Customize worked for me. And Google can't tell left from right. It was the Swipe Left toggle I had to disable.